# TableView column that is not bound to a certain bean property

Tags: javafx, tableview, refresh

```
TableView<A>
```

I use a custom `CellValueFactory` and `CellFactory` to fill a `TableView`'s cell with another mini table, that displays different properties of `A`.

Therefore I came up with the following solution:

```
TableColumn<A, A> c1;

c1.setCellValueFactory(c -> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(c.getValue()));

CellFactory implements Callback<TableColumn<A, A>, TableCell<A, A>> {
@Override
    public TableCell<A, A> call(final TableColumn<A, A> param) {
    return new TableCell<A, A>() {

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(final A item, final boolean empty) {

        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty || this.getTableRow() == null) {
            setText(null);
            setStyle("");
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            TableView nestedTable = buildTable();
            setGraphic(nestedTable);
        }
        }
    };
    }
}
```

This solution is not optimal, as it will not update cells when items are refreshed.

How else would I implement a column, that is not bound to a single bean property? Should I introduce another property that does already contain the nested table? I think rather not, since rendering the table content is task for the mentioned factory classes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by introducing an intermediate bean, that holds all the properties that are needed to build the cell content.

```
TableColumn<A, CellBean> c1;

c1.setCellValueFactory(c -> c.cellBeanProperty()));

CellFactory implements Callback<TableColumn<A, CellBean>, TableCell<A, CellBean>> {
@Override
    public TableCell<A, CellBean> call(final TableColumn<A, CellBean> param) {
    return new TableCell<A, CellBean>() {

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(final CellBean item, final boolean empty) {

        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty || this.getTableRow() == null) {
            setText(null);
            setStyle("");
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            TableView nestedTable = buildTable(item);
            setGraphic(nestedTable);
        }
        }
    };
    }
}
```